# Webpack implicit vendor bundle with polyfill bundle

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

I would like to build three bundles: `main.js`, `vendor.js` and `polyfill.js`. `polyfill.js` file should contain the modules defined in `polyfill.js` file. `vendor.js` file should be dynamically created by extracting all the dependencies imported from npm(`node_modules`). Finally `main.js` should contain other than `polyfill` and `vendor` modules, which is essentially my app code.

**polyfill.js**

```
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
```

**main.js**

```
import { NgModule, ApplicationRef } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';

@NgModule([
    imports: [...]
])
class AppModule {
}
```

I've written following webpack config but always get following error:

```
"CommonsChunkPlugin: While running in normal mode it's not allowed to use a non-entry chunk (main)",
    "CommonsChunkPlugin: While running in normal mode it's not allowed to use a non-entry chunk (vendor)"
```

**webpack.config.prod.js**

```
{
  entry: {
    polyfill: './polyfill.ts',
    main: './main.ts'
  },
  output: {
    publicPath: options.assetPath
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
      minChunks: function (module) {
        const check = module.context && module.context.indexOf('node_modules') !== -1;        
        module.originalChunkNames = module.chunks.map(chunk=> chunk.name);
        return check;
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'polyfill',
      chunks: ['vendor'],
      minChunks: ({ originalChunkNames }) => originalChunkNames.includes('polyfill'),
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      names: ['main', 'vendor', 'polyfill'],
      minChunks: Infinity
    })
  ]
}
```

Here what I would like to do is dynamically create `vendor` bundle including all `node_modules` I import in my source files. Create `polyfill` bundle by including all module explicitly defined in `polyfill.js` file. And the final `main` bundle.

**I've tried lots of example from webpack github repo but none of them helped me to achieve something like above mentioned**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a [Github repository](https://github.com/lekhnath/webpack-implicit-vendor-with-polyfill) to demonstrate the working example.

Below is important part of webpack configuration to achieve this type of output:

```
{
  entry: {
    polyfill: 'polyfill.ts',
    main: 'main.ts'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: "vendor",
      chunks: ["main"],
      minChunks: function(module) {
        const check =
          module.context && module.context.indexOf("node_modules") !== -1;
        module.originalChunkNames = module.chunks.map(chunk => chunk.name);
        return check;
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: "polyfill",
      chunks: ["vendor"],
      minChunks: function({ originalChunkNames }) {
        return originalChunkNames.includes("polyfill");
      }
    }),
  ]
}
```

Comment: Do you already have a Webpack 4 version of this config? Struggling with this in WP4.